# what's wrong with exception handling

Tags: python

When I enter a letter for one of the numbers I get an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/rodchar/Documents/Hello World Katie/testing.py", line 7, in <module>
        x = input("What is your first number?")
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 's' is not defined



x = 0
y = 0

isValid = False

while isValid == False:
    x = input("What is your first number?")

    try:
        float(x)
        isValid = True
    except:
        isValid = False

    y = input("What is your second number?")

    try:
        float(y)
        isValid = True
    except:
        isValid = False


print "The answer is: %s" % (x+y)
```

Comment: Is there a better way to write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, at least in Python 2.7, `input()` is not what you want for getting user input. You actually want `raw_input()`. (This is, indeed, confusing, and has been fixed in Python 3.)

Secondly, as @jamylak said, the statement giving the exception is not inside a try/catch block.

Thirdly, when you catch exceptions using `except:`, you should really be catching a specific type of exception (`except ValueError:`) instead of any and all exceptions. Catching all exceptions is bad because it masks bugs that raise exceptions you didn't anticipate.

---

A better way to write this would be:

- Apply the "Don't Repeat Yourself" principle (DRY) - the code for getting `x` and getting `y` from the user is very similar. Instead of writing the same thing twice, write it once and reuse it.
- Wrap the "get a float from the user" functionality up in a named function.
- Catch only the specific type of exception that you are prepared to handle.

Tested on Python 2.7:

```
def get_float_from_user (prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = float(raw_input(prompt))
            return user_input
        except ValueError:
            print ("Not a floating point number. Please try again.")

x = get_float_from_user("Enter x.")
y = get_float_from_user("Enter y.")

print (x+y)
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than the question deserves :)

Answer (score 3):

`input()` tries to evaluate its input as a python expression...
So it tries to evaluate `s` and looks for a variable `s`.

In this case you could set `x` to a string:

```
x = raw_input("What is your first number?")
```

then do the conversion to float in a `try` block

**Note:** This only applies to python 2 as python 3 changes the `input()` function to take input as a string.

Comment: Entering `s` as the input to `x = input("prompt>>")` doesn't try to assign `x = s`. Instead, it tries to evaluate the statement `s` as if you entered it at the Python interpreter.

Comment: Actually, Python 2.7's `input()` does not return anything at all. `input(prompt)` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `input`, `eval` is called on the text the user passes. In this case, the result of `eval('s')` is the value of the variable `s`, which isn't defined. So you get a name error. If you want to pass a *string*, you have to enter it as a string, with `'` marks around it. In other words, not `s` but `'s'`.

Quoting the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input):

> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised.

This is changed in Python 3, which I didn't initially mention because I figured it would be best not to complicate things, and you're obviously using Python 2. But `input` in [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#input) is equivalent to [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) in Python 2.