# Validating user options - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't seem to be able to do this. I have a big program which needs modifying slightly.

All I need to do is ensure that the user cannot proceed until a valid option has been entered. Anything other than '1', '2', '3' and '4' is invalid.

```
def GetResponse():
    global Response
    Response = (input("Enter Option number: "))
```

If this is the code, the menu continues to show when anything is entered. Nothing happens, other than the menu continuing to come up. (string or any numbers), but if I modify it slightly and make the response integer only:

```
def GetResponse():
    global Response
    Response = (int(input("Enter Option number: ")))
```

Then here if a valid option is entered it takes you to that option, whereas if I enter a piece of text is comes up with an error (expected I know)

What I'm confused about is why, when I change is to int, only then will it respond to options entered, whereas if I take the int away, I get no errors but at the same time the program doesn't respond to valid inputs.

Sorry if this is unclear information. It's the best way I could explain it.
An actual response

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Also we usually use `lower_case` for variables and functions, reserving `CamelCase` for classes. Also it would be better to return a response instead of modifying a global variable.

Comment: To elaborate on @katrielalex's suggestion: Globals are bad - they encourage a coding style which allows any part of the program to modify values used by other parts of the program. This leads to problems when one part of your code changes a value when you didn't expect it to, and the entire program blows up in your face.

Comment: I've fixed the indentation so the code will pass syntax checks.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.x, `input` evaluates the entered text.  `int` raises a ValueError if you pass it something that can't be converted to an integer.

So the reason that it works with numbers is that numbers evaluate to numbers -- just like they do at the Python command line. I'll bet if you put `print "hello world"` into your example, you won't get the same error as if you entered `zzzz`. The first is valid Python, the second isn't.

It would probably make more sense to use raw_input, since it's unlikely that you want the Python interpreter to interpret the entered text -- what if the user enters `import sys; sys.exit()`?

I think the right thing to do here would be to take the input, try to convert it to an int, and re-prompt if it throws an error.

```
choice = None
while not choice:
    val = raw_input("Enter Option Number: ")
    try:
        choice = int(val)
    except ValueError:
        print("Must be an integer 1 to 4")
```

Comment: I use Python 3. That doesn't use raw_input does it?

Comment: yes. You can replace `input` by `raw_input`. Most people use python 2.X. If you want help about python 3.X please provide the appropriate tag.

Comment: @JoeTaylor: Ah - Py3k. Explains a lot. Just so you know, unless you say you are using Python 3, we will generally assume you're using Python 2 (which is quite different) and give advice which applies to Python 2. For questions like this the difference is very significant, so *always* tell us if you're using Python 3.

Comment: @JoeTaylor: if you're learning Python, you will find more resources for Python 2 than 3. You shouldn't use Python 3 just because it's the latest version. There are still plenty of Python libraries which don't work with Python 3. The creator of Python made some changes which deliberately broke backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Integers and Characters/Strings are different types in Python.  For instance, `'1'` isn't the same as `1`.

If your menu option looked something like:

```
if 1 <= input <= 4:
    # Valid input, find the menu
```

...then you're checking for integers.

Hope that made sense.

Comment: Or floats, or any of the other numeric types supported by Python. A fun bug would be code that worked fine if the user entered "1", or "5", and correctly refused input like "bacon sandwich" - but which would throw up on user input like "1.5".

Answer (score 0):

Plagiarising from another [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882670/whats-wrong-with-exception-handling/9882723#9882723):

In Python 2.7, `input()` is not what you want for getting user input. You actually want `raw_input()`. (This is, indeed, **confusing**, and has been fixed in Python 3.)

The difference is that `input()` takes user input and then tries to evaluate it *as if you typed it as a command into an interactive Python session*. Function calls and expressions are evaluated, which leads to some "what?!" moments if you try to use it for general-purpose user input:

```
In [18]: my_number = input("Please enter a number >> ")
Please enter a number >> locals() # unexpected user input

In [19]: print (my_number)
{'disp': <function disp at 0x029FBEB0>, 'all': <function all at 0x0290BA70>,
 'dist': <function dist at 0x030D1430>, 'issubsctype': <function issubsctype
 at 0x028FADF0>, 'sca': <function sca at 0x062AF370>, 'savez': <function
 savez at 0x02A8E830>, 'entropy': <function entropy at 0x030C8F70>,
 'restoredot': <built-in function restoredot>, 'ptp': <function ptp at
 0x0290BB30>, 'Subplot': <class 'matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot'>, 'frange':
 <function frange at 0x030D1930>, 'PackageLoader': <class
 numpy._import_tools.PackageLoader at 0x0248C8B8>, 'rec2csv':
 <function rec2csv at 0x030FE4B0>, 'ylabel': <function ylabel at 0x062AF6F0>, ....
# what?!
```

Instead, use `raw_input()` which asks the user for an input, then returns whatever they typed as a string.

Reading the documentation for [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) and [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) may help clarify this.

---

Ah, you're using Python 3. In that case, try the [approach I suggested in the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882670/whats-wrong-with-exception-handling/9882723#9882723) - define a function that loops forever until it gets valid user input, then returns (thus breaking the loop.)

Python 2.x code to get floats: adapt for Python 3 and to get ints. (This is left as a trivial exercise for you.)

```
def get_float_from_user (prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = float(raw_input(prompt))
            return user_input
        except ValueError:
            print ("Not a floating point number. Please try again.")

x = get_float_from_user("Enter x.")
y = get_float_from_user("Enter y.")

print (x+y)
```